# How to interrupt a thread by button listener

Tags: java, android, runnable, thread-sleep, interrupted-exception

I have a button listener witch include a thread sleep and another button listener.

Second button listener must interrupt this thread and I don t know how to do this:

My code:

```
button1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


..........


                button1.setEnabled(false);
                button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2.setEnabled(true);


                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2800);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          // ???????
                        }

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                button1.setEnabled(true);
                                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                button2.setEnabled(false);
                                button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();



 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


..............


         //  Thread.interrupted(); -> does not work


                    }
                });

}   });
```

How can I make button2 listener to interrupt the thread?

Comment: Did you try `thread.interrupt();`?

Comment: yes i tried but as Randev said does not work with anonymus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an anonymous implementation of the thread, make the thread a class variable. Suppose the name of the thread is btnOneThread

```
private Thread btnOneThread;
```

Initialize the thread where needed and start it.

```
btnOneThread = new Thread( ){...}
btnOneThread.start();
```

When the button2 is clicked call

```
if (btnOneThread != null) {
    btnOneThread.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   class TestInterruptingThread1 extends Thread{  
        public void run(){  
        try{  
        Thread.sleep(1000);  
        System.out.println("task");  
        }catch(InterruptedException e){  
        throw new RuntimeException("Thread interrupted..."+e);  
        }  

        }  

    b2 //
   {
    try{  
        t1.interrupt();  // t1 is the thread to be interrupted
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Exception handled "+e);}  

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling the thread.interrupt() method. You also need to save your Thread instance in a field of your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread t = new Thread() {...}
t.start();
```

and in the listener:

```
t.interrupt();
```

As to

```
//  Thread.interrupted(); -> does not work
```

it will work from within a class derived from Thread and will be the same as `this.interrupted()`; `t.interrupted()` will work outside of the class definition.

Also note that the method [`isInterrupted()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted()) does not clear the interruption flag, while [`interrupted()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) *has the side-effect of clearing the flag*.